# table row updates on second click. form validation javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a form using javascript. The text fields are embedded within table rows. A blank table row is left to display warnings (like "cannot be blank"). When I am calling the method validateForm() on onsubmit the warning appears in the table row and disappears. And when I press the button the second time then the warning stays on the html page. I don't know whats happening.

```
function validateForm() {
var warnmsg = checkNames();
document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML = warnmsg;
}
function checkNames() {
var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
if (fname.value.length==0)
    return "Cannot be left blank";
else
    return "";
```

}

Comment: You should also add the HTML source of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return false in order for the page not to leave.

```
            function validateForm() 
            {
                var warnmsg = checkNames();
                document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML = warnmsg;
                return !warnmsg.length >0;//if there is a warning message, return false
            }
```

then in your form:

```
onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

here's my test page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function validateForm() 
            {
                var warnmsg = checkNames();
                document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML = warnmsg;
                return !warnmsg.length >0;
            }
            function checkNames() 
            {
                var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
                if (fname.value.length==0)
                    return "Cannot be left blank";
                else
                    return "";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                    <p id="row1"></p>
            <input type="text" id="fname" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did as you said. the warning appears and disappears suddenly on first click. When I click it the second time, the warning stays on the page.

Comment: really? that's weird. everything seems to be working when I tried it

Comment: @AmerSohail when you say the second time the message stays on the page, have you debugged the page and ensured that your validateForm function was invoked?  I'd probably start stepping into this if i were you.

Comment: @AmerSohail—sounds like the form is submitting and refreshing the page. Check that you've attached the listener as shown by MikeB.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var warnmsg = checkNames;
```